# Can a discontinuous function be integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration

In the chapter on integration in Micheal spivak's book Calculus, when he was proving theorem 8 he showed a figure of the integral of a discontinuous function (available at the end of this question). My question is, how can a discontinuous function be integrable? If the integral of a function is the area under the curve, how can we calculate an area which is not fully closed from it's beginning to it's end?

[image: Graph of a discontinuous (at a point) function thats integrable]

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and its set of discontinuities has measure zero. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124012/f-is-riemann-integrable-if-the-set-of-discontinuities-is-measure-zero for more information. This is called the "Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability". The point is, the Riemann integral doesn't care if there is a "small amount" of discontinuities.

Comment: @Abdelrahman Consider piecewise constant functions, for instance.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow But the Riemann integral is the area How can we calculate the area if it's not closed

Comment: @Abdelrahman If the set of discontinuities has measure zero you can always choose partition points for the Riemann sum that avoid the discontinuities. Note that the only type of discontinuity that is allowed is a jump discontinuity because poles are not bounded.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I understand what you are referring but the area is not fully closed how we can calculate ?

Comment: That's the point though... it doesn't have to be a continuous function. Saying the integral is the area under a curve is slightly informal. More accurately, it is the limit of a sequence of Riemann sums. If you read and understand the proof of the Lebesgue criterion, you will see exactly how you can calculate it. It's like what CyclotomicField said: you can choose partitions that avoid the discontinuities.

Comment: @Abdelrahman you just do it piecewise. Calculate the area between every discontinuity and add them up on the region of integration.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow So the problem is our intuitive definition for the integral (that's the area under the curve) and if we defined it as limit of sums our problem will be solved

Comment: @CyclotomicField Can you provide a good book for more deep understanding for the integral or I can stick with Michael spivak book ?

Comment: @Abdelrahman you can still use your intuition about area. Take a rectangle and set the area up as an integral. Now cut a square off the top right corner. There will be two regions with a jump discontinuity where the vertical cut is. The area will just be the area before the cut plus the area after the cut. The boundedness ensures we can't create infinite poles, the measure zero for the discontinuities ensures that there is always a little integrable portion between the discontinuous points.

Comment: @CyclotomicField another question does the integral meaning is the area or the area just an informal definition ?

Comment: @Abdelrahman in higher mathematics the area will be defined using the integral, not the other way around. It's called measure theory.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Can you tell the precise definition of the integral if you can't write in comment can you provide any link or a book that talks about the precise definition

Comment: @Abdelrahman the two main types of integration are Riemann and Lebesgue. The Riemann integral uses Riemann sums and limits. You should start with that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral

Comment: Try the derivative of the [Ramp function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ddx+Ramp%28x%29+) or the [integral of the Heaviside theta function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+heavisidetheta%28x%29)

Comment: Integrals come from thinking about how to compute areas of shapes which are not bounded by straight lines. As soon as you start with a basic unit of a rectangle (or cuboid of appropriate dimension) and try to fit a curved line or surface you are into a problem which will involve limits. It turns out that if you want your definition of "area" or "volume" or "length" to have good properties (so you can add the areas of disjoint sets, for example) you end up being able to compute the area of things you didn't think of at first.

Comment: @CyclotomicField How can we "do it piecewise. Calculate the area between every discontinuity and add them" if the set of discontinuities is dense, e.g. the rationals in an interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "area" doesn't exist unless you assign a meaning to that word. In Calculus, one generally refers to a bounded real valued function $f$ on the real numbers being integrable on an interval $[a,b]$ iff
$$\begin{align}\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nm_i(t_i-t_{i-1})\colon \{t_1,\dots,t_n\}\text{ partition of }[a,b]\right\}\\=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nM_i(t_i-t_{i-1})\colon\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}\text{ partition of }[a,b]\right\}\end{align}$$
Where $m_i=\inf\{f(x)\colon t_{i-1}\leq x\leq t_i\}$ and $M_i=\sup\{f(x)\colon t_{i-1}\leq x\leq t_i\}$, the integral of an integrable $f$ is defined as any of this two equal values (That's the exact definition from Spivaik, Calculus). Generaly (in calculus), by **area** under the graph of a non-negative function on the interval $[a,b]$, we mean the integral of said function on the interval $[a,b]$ (if it exists). That's it. Thats a definition, no argument needed.

Note that the function $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$ with $\int_{-1}^1f=0$ (you can check this directly from the definition, it's a good exercise), that is, the area under this discontinuous function is $0$ (despite it not being $0$ everywhere). A more extravagant function with this same pathology (also present in Spivak's) is the [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

For a more intuitive discontinuous function (on infinitely many points) whose integral probably fits your intuitive notion of "area", are the [floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

In general, concepts mean nothing in math until defined. On spivak you will find continuous functions on a point where it "doesn't look continuous". It doesn't matter if it "looks continuous" or not, all that matters is if it fits the definition or not.

Comment: con pebre ,so our intuition can be sometimes misleading and in math what we all care about is the definition even if it doesn't agree with our intuition

Comment: Your intuition will be trained until you can pretty much know if a statement in calculus is true or not by just reading the statement. Mahtematical intuition is VERY important and it comes with practice, math often doesn't behave like the real world and much like you have developed and intuition for real life you will develop mathematical intuition. Although intuition is important, a statement cannot be considere true until it has been shown that it follows from the definition and axioms you have stablished; if it's true (or false) then it's true (or false), no matter what your intuition says.

Comment: I want to ask you another question ,I've read a paper from Sydney university that was talking about integrals that the precise meaning of integral is not the area instead the meaning of the integral is limit of sums ,Is this the correct definition about it ? If so why this is the correct one? The link of the paper (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sydney.edu.au/content/dam/students/documents/mathematics-learning-centre/integration-definite-integral.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjk6oz2x7_3AhWThv0HHc9MBvMQFnoECBYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1_u21uO8jUh0t_2sWY5Sti)

Comment: @Abdelrahman since I guess you are already reading Spivak, I will refer you to the Apendix of Chapter 13: Rieman sums. Here a new object is defined (Rieman sums), Theorem 1 of this apendix proves that the limit of this sums are nothing but the integral (as defined by my answer to this question). The integral, in this appendix, is presented as the limit of sums. Riemann sums are what the paper you where reading was talking about. Wiki for Riemann sums: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Comment: @Abdelrahman if you are interested on training your math intuition, I recommend taking a look at the book "Counter Examples in Analysis", it's fun and easy to read yet very insightful.

Comment: ,Then the solution to the problem I was asking was definitely To stick with the definition of area that was proposed in the book and to accept that the standard intuitive notion about the area is not right here,Am I thinking right?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer,You are saying that the integral defines the area and not the other way around then obviously we've derived the concept of integral besides the area, Can you provide any book that can give me a deep understanding for the precise definition of the integral and how we derived it? Because thinking about the integral as the area is not really helpful

Comment: @The_Sympathizer, Because any Calculus book I've read begin with defining the integral as the area, a confusion then happens to me because we began by the definition of area then how suddenly we say that the definition of area is not the precise one unless that we've defined it from the beginning by the precise one

Comment: @Abdelrahman : Yes, you're right (and I don't have any better book suggestions; they're all pretty much written in the same way so I don't think they'd help.). I'm also less sure if that particular comment was very helpful as I think it about more, though since it can't be edited I just removed it and suggest you should disregard it, too.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer, Can you provide any resources that I can learn what I've asked,Can you tell your own resources that you have learned from it the precise meaning of integral

Comment: @Abdelrahman: The "precise meaning of the integral" is in fact exactly what has been written in this answer, or something else that is logically equivalent to it in that each assign identical numerical values in identical situations. I think what you'd really like is a better exposition on/discussion of the relationships between this idea of integrals and the idea of areas.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer ,My problem is that in all of my study of calculus I learned that the integral is the area and the integral and the area is the same thing and there is no difference between them and then I found out that the concept of integration has a meaning other than the area ,what confuses me how this concept has another meaning and it was derived from the concept of area ?

Comment: @Abdelrahman: Right, and that's a problem with whatever you were taught. There is, actually, a difference. I was preparing a long writeup about this that while it wouldn't necessarily be useful for comments directly, could be potentially useful elsewhere. What I would instead suggest is that there are at least two different ways of conceptualizing the ideas of "integral" and "area" and the logical relationships amongst them, one of which likely parallels the "textbook" approach in full, and the other of which is probably not seen much if at all therein.

Comment: I am being asked to move this to chat - so I will do so. Do you mind?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer 
First of all I want to thank you and all the other users that were trying to help
secondly:Could you suggest for me a step that I can took  to resolve my problem with what I was taught and gives me the understanding of the difference that you were refering and also gives me the correct mathematical meaning of (Integration)